# Capturing exceptions from a Page in a usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can a user control capture the Page.Error event of it's parent page and log that exception?

Comment: should it be doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it is not the best solution it only works if the error occurs after the event has been registered, which means after the control loads, since the page loads first it won't catch any errors in the page load.  A better solution would be to use the Application_Error event in the global.asax.

Put this code in your control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Error += new EventHandler(Page_Error);
}

void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    Response.Write(exception.ToString());

    HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: My rational for using a user control was to capture any unhandled exceptions for a set of pages. Would a Master Page Error event handler be a better place to capture such exceptions?

Comment: I would place the logging in the application_error event, that way you are logging all errors.  If you need to do something special for a specific set of pages you could check the request.url to see what page the error happened on, and do something appropriate.  Having said that the master page would probably work just as well I just have never done it that way.